# How to use Proxy to watch if a variable is (no longer) undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

Please, forgive my n00bility...
I am trying to use Proxy to execute some code after a global var stage is no longer undefined. Here's my naive attempt:

```

```js
var stage = undefined
let myObj;
let st = {
    stage: stage,
}
let lr = {
    get: function(obj:any, prop:any):LightRay{
        myObj = new SomeObjThatNeedsStage(obj[prop]) // <= supposed to be non-undefined stage
        return myObj
    },
}
let p = new Proxy(st, lr)
// At this point I expect the lr handler to have been executed if the stage var has been instantiated by some external code that's out of my control.
```

```

Obviously, I misunderstand how the Proxy works, but I tried various scenarios, non of which works. Passing the undefined stage as a target to the proxy doesn't work (getting `Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler` error). How can I use Proxy in this scenario? Why can't I `observe` the undefined stage with Proxy until it is instantiated, and then execute the callback?

FYI:

Stage var is global and I do not have control over it (it is instantiated by create.js at some point). All code is executed from a UMD module. I'm using typescript (transpiling down to es5). Object.defineProperty() is available in my browser. Also, the stage (of type createjs.Stage), when instantiated, does contain setter/getter of a different type, which makes it problematic when working with typescript.

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you want to write code to watch for a global variable's value to change?

Comment: What is supposed to define `stage` variable?

Comment: Re the FYI: Watching for the change is an anti-pattern and code maintenance nightmare. Look for any other solution you can, such as making the one module dependent on the other so you know it's loaded before your module runs.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a bad idea, but I have to deal with it because of weird way Adobe Animate CC exports Create.js code and Create.js annoyingly doesn't emit an ('ready') event that would tell me that the stage is up and running. It is outside of my control.

Comment: "*How can I use Proxy in this scenario?*" - you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer

You've said you don't control how `stage` is set.

Watching for the change is an anti-pattern and code maintenance nightmare. Look for any other solution you can, such as making the one module dependent on the other so you know it's loaded before your module runs.

However, you've said there is no other way, so:

You can't use Proxy for this, because in order for it to be effective, the code setting `stage` would have to set it via the proxy, not directly.

You've said you don't control how `stage` is declared. That means you can't use `Object.defineProperty` for this, either, because the property on the global object that `var` creates has `configurable: false`.

If there's absolutely, positively no way to get coordination between your module and whatver's doing `stage`, you'll have to resort to a timer loop. This is not a good idea, but may be your only real option:

```
var stop = Date.now() + 30000;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof stage !== "undefined" || Date.now() > stop) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
        // Your code here, if `stage` is still undefined, you hit the timeout
    }
}, 50); // 50ms interval or whatever you need
```

---

### Original answer

**By far** the best solution here is: Don't do that. Instead, use an object with a setter:

```
var stuff = {
    _stage: undefined,
    get stage() {
        return _stage;
    },
    set stage(value) {
        if (_stage === undefined && value !== undefined) {
            _stage = value;
            // Trigger your code here
        }
    }
};
```

Then have the other code doing this set `stuff.stage` rather than setting `stage`.

Comment: we can use `Object.defineProperty` for this kind of purpose?

Comment: @zabusa: Yes, but it's not guaranteed to work with host-provided objects. (That said: It probably works with `window`/the global object.)

Comment: Yes, never had issues with window/document and getter.

Comment: @dfsq: Good good. Browsers have been much, much better at making their host-provided objects JS-compatible the last several years.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder , please note the (FYI) update in my question. So how would I Proxy on window to accomplish my goal? And what about the getter/setter option? Both seem to be viable solutions to my problem. Can you provide examples?

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski: Do you control the declaration of `stage`, or does the other code do that part, too?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not control stage's declaration. I could, but I'm told not to (for valid, editorial reasons).

Comment: Ah, I arrived at a similar (actually marginally better) solution on my own awhile ago, but was hoping there is a nicer way to do it. Thanks for your efforts though :)

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski: I'm curious what it was.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see my answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my answer was in haste. Didn't pay enough attention to your updated version. My apologies. Just had a closer look at your answer. It is essentially the same, yours being with the added benefit of timing out the timer it it takes too long, So I revoke my answer. Yours is definitely better. Cheers.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to watch `stage` change when it gets defined by something else, and `stage` is global, then simple solution is to use old good getter:

```
let myObj;

Object.defineProperty(window, 'stage1', {
  set (value) {
    myObj = new SomeObjThatNeedsStage(stage)
    return value
  }
})
```

In the above, make sure you don't have `var stage = undefined` you don't need it anymore.

Comment: ...provided `defineProperty` works on the global object, which on browsers is host-provided; host-provided objects don't necessarily have to support this. Separately: `set` shouldn't return the value, and you'll presumably need a `get`.

Comment: Doesn't work. The setter never gets called. BTW, yes, stage is global and I do not have control over it. the code you provided is executed from a UMD module. I'm using typescript (transpiling down to es5). Object.defineProperty() is available in my browser.